# Perl Regex: Negative lookaheads

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have this test text:

```
cake/app/webroot/js/compiled/shop.js
cake/app/webroot/js/compiled/shop.min.js
cake/app/webroot/js/good/thing.js
```

When I try this:

```
/^(?!.*compiled)(?!.*min).*$/
```

It doesn't match anything. But when I add:

```
/^.*
```

to the beginning, it matches something on each line. (I only want the last line matched.)

What am I missing?

Comment: It does select the last line right?  https://regex101.com/r/toNjzp/1

Answer (score 2):

Your first regex matches the third line

```
my $re = qr/^(?!.*compiled)(?!.*min).*$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/$re/) {
        say 'OK : ', $_;
    } else {
        say 'KO';
    }
}


__DATA__
cake/app/webroot/js/compiled/shop.js
cake/app/webroot/js/compiled/shop.min.js
cake/app/webroot/js/good/thing.js
```

**Output:**

```
KO
KO
OK : cake/app/webroot/js/good/thing.js
```

---

When you add `.*` at the beginning, it matches the whole line then the negative lookahead is true, there is no `compiled` or `min` after the regex has consume all the characters, so the match is true.